# tkinter frame not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid, frame

Can anyone help me why `columnspan` not having any effect in this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frametop = tk.Frame(root).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
labeltest1 = tk.Label(frametop, text="A").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
labeltest2 = tk.Label(frametop, text="B").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
labeltest3 = tk.Label(frametop, text="C").grid(row = 0, column = 2)

framebottom = tk.Frame(root).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
labeltest4 = tk.Label(framebottom, text="Hello World").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
labeltest5 = tk.Label(framebottom, text="Hello World").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
labeltest6 = tk.Label(framebottom, text="Hello World").grid(row = 1, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

`labeltest1`, `labeltest2`, `labeltest3` are being distributed in column  similar to the widgets of `framebottom`. What I wanted is a grid of 3 columns inside a `frame` with a `columnspan = 2` with the same row.
Something similar to this:

```
||   A    |   B   |   C    ||  
| Hello World | Hello World | Hello World |
```

Comment: columns in different frames are completely unrelate to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is organized, the `Frames` have no effect; when you `grid` on the same line as the widget creation, `None` gets returned and stored in the variables you are using for the `Frames`, and `Label`. A consequence is that the labels are inserted directly into `root`.

The following does the same, with a placement of the labels per your request.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text="A").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
tk.Label(root, text="B").grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2)
tk.Label(root, text="C").grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=2)

tk.Label(root, text="Hello World").grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
tk.Label(root, text="Hello World").grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=3)
tk.Label(root, text="Hello World").grid(row=1, column=6, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

#### GUI appearance (osX):

[image]